# Converting String to Date in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, locale

I am programming in java, and have a little problem since yesterday in parsing Date (converting from String to Date).

I am getting this exception :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri May 24 18:47:31
>   GMT+01:00 2013"

Here is my code:

```
String db= obj.getDebut(); // = "Fri May 24 18:47:31 GMT+01:00 2013"
String pattern2 = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy";
Date datedebutEntree = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern2).parse(db);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: that was a problem in application language , i added locale.ENGLISH and that w orked , thank yoou for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application language appears to be `French`. If your default `Locale` is likewise, it 
will throw a `ParseException` when attempting to parse English day and month fields. Use `Locale.ENGLISH` instead:

```
String pattern2 = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
Date datedebutEntree = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern2, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat the `Z` pattern. Use this:

```
String pattern2 = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
```

Comment: I Still have the exception :

Comment: mai 18, 2013 7:08:41 PM GUI.gestionReservations ajouterActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri May 24 19:08:36 GMT+01:00 2013"

Comment: You're on a French locale :)